# How to use .NET high performance logging LoggerMessage together with Serilog advanced destructure?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, logging, serilog

Note: I am using .NET 8 and `Microsoft.Extensions.Telemetry.Abstractions`, so the source generator triggered by `LoggerMessageAttribute` is not the same as the old one...

My goal is to get the benefits of .NET high performance logging and also use Serilog's advanced destructure features to enhance log structure.

(A valid answer could be, that satisfying both requirements at the same time is not possible, and Serilog destructure does not fit to the high performance scenario, however in this case the question is: can we make it *configurable* which requirement want I priorize, with the same code base instead of rewrite tens of thousands of logging code lines)

So instead of:

```
    // Serilog automatically and in a configurable way destructures forecast
    _logger.LogInformation("Generated forecast {@forecast}", forecast);
```

I have the following method:

```
    [LoggerMessage(Level = LogLevel.Information, Message = "Generated {@forecast} forecast")]
    public partial void GeneratedForecast(ILogger logger, WeatherForecast forecast);
```

which gives a source generator error message:

```
Error   LOGGEN031   Logging method "GeneratedForecast" has template(s) that start with "@":
```

Clearly this is forbidden, with no further reasoning in the error message.

What am I missing here? Am I trying to do something which is inherently impossible?

(I do know `[LogProperties]` and `[TagProvider]` attributes but the destructure capabilities are limited.)

Comment: (For other readers) Decent article covering how the MS codegen works and its capabilities https://andrewlock.net/behind-logproperties-and-the-new-telemetry-logging-source-generator/#logging-whole-objects-with-the-logproperties-attribute

Comment: The source generator for LoggerMessageAttribute doesn't support Serilog's `@` operator for destructuring. Possible solutions include:

1. A method to handle destructuring before calling the generated logger.
2. Use Serilog for detailed logs and .NET logging for performance, though it may affect overall efficiency.
3.Check for updates or enhancements in LoggerMessageAttribute that might support better integration.
4.Configure your application to switch between detailed logging and high-performance logging based on specific requirements.